# setting up GCC and Make for Jekyll

Tags: gcc, makefile, jekyll, codeblocks, github-pages

I'm trying to preview my GitHub Pages locally (to edit the CSS), or create a Jekyll website, from Windows. Following the [Jekyll insruction](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/), I installed Ruby and Gems, including Jekyll itself. The instruction points me also to [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) and [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) as other requirements, but I'm confused. The GCC page is a list of non-link names of many packages that I don't know how to install, and the Make page leads to a series of `tar.lz.sig` that also I don't know how to use on Windows. A search for "GCC" led me to [CodeBlocks](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/), and I downloaded `codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe` that supposedly contains the GCC. I ran this exe, it installed CodeBlocks. Then, upon getting launched, CodeBlocks "can't find compiler executable". Some solution online says to fix the path by locating the mingw folder in Program Files, but my Program Files doesn't have a mingw folder. I did a search for "mingw" over my entire `C:`, and nothing came up. I re-installed `codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe` and also tried `codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe`, and I still don't have the mingw folder, CodeBlocks still isn't detecting the GCC.

(By the way, when I was previously setting up GitHub Desktop, I used Git Bash, and in it I might have seen something like "mingw", but after that the app won't launch again when I click on "Open" or "Run as adminstrator" from Windows Start menu.)

Comment: Installing GCC and Make on Windows are well covered in existing questions, but if you have not done this sort of thing before, you are going to end up way out of your depth. Is there a reason you are not following the [instructions for Windows users?](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/)